# Is there anything to Firefox electrolysis / 56 as MATE is to GNOME 3?

Tags: firefox, fork, add-on, gnome-3

Have there been any forks of firefox to continue maintenance and development of the pre-electrolysis based design?

I think that some rebellion against the break of addon ecosystem compatibility is needed, and find it hard to imagine there has been none.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the closest there is to something trying to keep the spirit of the original vision alive is Waterfox.